# Spigot Plugin - KitPvP kit abilities

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I have been working on a plugin for the past few weeks and I have run into a problem when using the kit. Each kit has its own "ability" and it is activated when you right-click the certain item in your inventory. For example, the "Archer" kit when you right-click the slimeball it will turn into a magma cream and enchant the bow to flame until you run out of magma from shooting the arrow's. I would love some help so thank you in advance.

```java
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.enchantments.Enchantment;
import org.bukkit.entity.*;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityShootBowEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Archer extends Kit implements Listener {

    public ArrayList<Player> fireArrows = new ArrayList<Player>();
    public HashMap<Player, Integer> arrowCount = new HashMap<Player, Integer>();

    public Archer() {
        super("Archer", "kitpvp.Archer");
    }

    @Override
    public ItemStack displayItem() {
        ItemStack itemStack = new ItemStack(Material.BOW);
        ItemMeta itemMeta = itemStack.getItemMeta();
        itemMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GOLD + getName() + " Kit");
        itemStack.setItemMeta(itemMeta);
        return itemStack;
    }

    public ItemStack displayItemShop() {
        ItemStack shop = new ItemStack(Material.BOW);
        ItemMeta shopmeta = shop.getItemMeta();
        shopmeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GOLD + getName() + " Kit");
        List<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();
        price.add(ChatColor.YELLOW + "0 Coins");
        price.add(ChatColor.YELLOW + "");
        price.add(ChatColor.YELLOW + "Left-Click to Buy");
        price.add(ChatColor.YELLOW + "Right-Click to Preview");
        shopmeta.setLore(price);
        shop.setItemMeta(shopmeta);
        return shop;
    }

    public ItemStack Bow() {
        ItemStack Bow = new ItemStack(Material.BOW);
        ItemMeta BowMeta = Bow.getItemMeta();
        BowMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.WHITE + "Archer Bow");
        Bow.setItemMeta(BowMeta);
        return Bow;
    }


    public ItemStack MagmaCream() {
        ItemStack MagmaCream = new ItemStack(Material.MAGMA_CREAM, 1);
        ItemMeta MagmaCreamMeta = MagmaCream.getItemMeta();
        MagmaCreamMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.YELLOW + "Right Click for Regular Arrows");
        MagmaCream.setItemMeta(MagmaCreamMeta);
        return MagmaCream;
    }

    public ItemStack SLIME_BALL() {
        ItemStack SLIME_BALL = new ItemStack(Material.SLIME_BALL, 1);
        ItemMeta SLIME_BALLMeta = SLIME_BALL.getItemMeta();
        SLIME_BALLMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.YELLOW + "Right Click for Fire Arrows");
        SLIME_BALL.setItemMeta(SLIME_BALLMeta);
        return SLIME_BALL;
    }


    @Override
    public Inventory kitPreview() {
        Inventory inventory = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 18, getName() + " Kit Preview");
        inventory.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.WOOD_SWORD));
        inventory.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.BOW));
        inventory.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.SULPHUR));
        inventory.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.ARROW));
        inventory.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_HELMET));
        inventory.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_CHESTPLATE));
        inventory.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_LEGGINGS));
        inventory.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_BOOTS));

        return inventory;
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(Player player) {
        player.removePotionEffect(PotionEffectType.JUMP);
        player.removePotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SPEED);
        player.removePotionEffect(PotionEffectType.REGENERATION);
        player.removePotionEffect(PotionEffectType.FIRE_RESISTANCE);
        player.removePotionEffect(PotionEffectType.DAMAGE_RESISTANCE);
        ItemStack sword = new ItemStack(Material.WOOD_SWORD);
        sword.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DAMAGE_ALL, 1);
        player.getInventory().setItem(0, sword);

        player.getInventory().setItem(2, SLIME_BALL());
        player.getInventory().setItem(1, Bow());
        player.getInventory().setItem(16, new ItemStack(Material.ARROW, 32));
        player.getInventory().setHelmet(new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_HELMET));
        player.getInventory().setChestplate(new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_CHESTPLATE));
        player.getInventory().setLeggings(new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_LEGGINGS));
        player.getInventory().setBoots(new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_BOOTS));
        for (int i = 0; i < player.getInventory().getSize(); i++) {
            if (player.getInventory().getItem(i) == null || player.getInventory().getItem(i).getType().equals(Material.AIR)) {
                player.getInventory().setItem(i, new ItemStack(Material.MUSHROOM_SOUP));
            }
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        Action action = e.getAction();
        if (action == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || action == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
            if (e.getItem().equals(MagmaCream())) {

                if (player.getInventory().contains(MagmaCream())) {
                    player.getInventory().removeItem(MagmaCream());
                    player.updateInventory();
                }
                fireArrows.remove(player);
                //Bow().removeEnchantment(Enchantment.ARROW_FIRE);
                player.updateInventory();
                player.getInventory().setItem(2, SLIME_BALL());

            } else if (e.getItem().equals(SLIME_BALL())) {
                if (player.getInventory().contains(Bow())) {
                    Bow().addEnchantment(Enchantment.ARROW_FIRE, 5);
                }
                player.updateInventory();
                player.getInventory().setItem(2, MagmaCream());
                fireArrows.add(player);
                if (player.getInventory().contains(Material.BOW)) {
                    Bow().getEnchantments();
                    Bow().addEnchantment(Enchantment.ARROW_FIRE, 5);
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&cYou now have a fire bow!"));

                    if (!(arrowCount.containsKey(player))) {
                        arrowCount.put(player, 0);
                    }

                    int firearrowcount = arrowCount.get(player);

                    arrowCount.put(player, firearrowcount + 1);

                    if (firearrowcount == 10) {
                        fireArrows.remove(player);
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&cYour fire arrows have ran out."));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question here? We are not a place to find somebody to do the work for you ^^. I f I was in your place, I would start by using an event to catch if the bow is tried to being used, and then look for the resource in the inventory.

Comment: I'm unsure what your question is. And also if you need help with Minecraft Spigot plugin development I'd recommend using Spigot's forums as there is not much Minecraft Spigot plugin developer here on StackOverflow.